# Having difficulty incrementing

Tags: java, for-loop, game-engine, increment

I'm having some difficulty incrementing my counter called right. Instead of incrementing it constantly prints out 1 and doesn't add the numbers together. I tried using another variable to total up the counter but no luck. Any ideas to why it is not incrementing?

Code:

```
    tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int wrong = 0;
    int right = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// enter key
        JTextField tf = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        letter = tf.getText();
        tf.setText("");
        // tf.requestFocus();
        jlLetsUsed.setText(jlLetsUsed.getText() + letter + " ");// sets

        char[] jlabelText = jlLines.getText().toCharArray();// converts

        char userEnteredChar = letter.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(wordList[level]);
        if (!wordList[level].contains(letter)) {
            wrong++;
            if (wrong == 6) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "He's dead, game over." + "\n"
                                + "The word was " + wordList[level]
                                + ".", "You Lost",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ic);
                GameStructure restart = new GameStructure();
                level = (int) (Math.random() * 64);// generate new
                                                    // random word
                restart.window();
            }
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < wordList[level].length(); i++) {
            if (wordList[level].charAt(i) == userEnteredChar) {
                jlabelText[3 * i] = ' ';
                jlabelText[3 * i + 1] = userEnteredChar;
                right++;
            }// end if
        }// end for
        jlLines.setText(String.valueOf(jlabelText));
        if (jlabelText.length / 3 == right) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You got the word!.",
                    "You Lost", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ic);
            GameStructure restart = new GameStructure();
            level = (int) (Math.random() * 64);// generate new
                                                // random word
            restart.window();
        }
    }// end actionPerformed method
});
```

Comment: Please clarify which variables you are talking about.

Comment: All this code is inside a loop, a method or in your main?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've commented "will not increment" on the variable

Comment: Where and how many times are you calling the method? Because the reason it's not increment may be a logic problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're expecting `right` to print the number of times you've guessed right, but it appears as though you call

```
int right = 0;
```

every time you guess.

Try loading up a word with at least 2 of the same letter, and guess that letter.  I'll bet that you see the number go up to 2 in that case.

---

If you want a number to increment every time you've guessed a correct letter, than you're going to have to declare it outside the scope of your guess.

Comment: Is there a way to just add up the values of right? If not, where should right be placed in order to increment correctly meaning even when theres duplicate letters in a word, it will increment twice.

Comment: @Anon  That depends.  Is all of that code that you've posted within another loop of some sort or within a method?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by declaring + initializing my right variable outside my method. Thanks for your help. I've updated my code above if anyone needs it as a reference.